# Mi App Store claim app issue with Play app signing

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console, android-keystore

I am trying to claim my app in the Mi app store.
The claim process in the Mi store is as follows

1. Download the unsigned apk from the Mi developer console.
2. Sign the unsigned apk with Keystore.

Now when I am signing the Mi apk with my release key(which is the upload key for play signing) I am getting the error

```
The signatures are inconsistent and the claim fails! Please upload again.
```

The problem is that the Mi store has scrapped my app from the Play store which is having the Play singing setup and because I am signing the apk with my upload key it's failing.

How can I sign in any unsigned apk with my google play release Keystore if Play Signing is enabled?

I went through so many blogs but couldn't find out the solution any help would be appreciated.

Reference

https://dev.mi.com/console/doc/detail?pId=882

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solutions for that?